# Nested loops for comparing 2 files

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am writing a program to compare two files. For each line in file 1, I want to compare it to all lines in file 2, then continue with the next line in file 1. The program is not continuing in file 1 after the first hit. Any suggestions?

Code: Select all

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import fileinput

# Open the two files
f1 = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
f2 = open(sys.argv[2], "r")

for line in f1:
    chrR,chrStart,chrEnd,name,score,strand1,codingStart,codingEnd,itemRbg,blockCount,blockSize,BlockStart = line.strip().split()
    chr = range(int(chrStart), int(chrEnd))
    lncRNA = set(chr)
    for line in f2:
        chrC,clustStart,clustEnd,annote,score,strand = line.strip().split()
        clust = range(int(clustStart), int(clustEnd))
        cluster = set(clust)
        if strand1 == '-':
            if chrR == chrC:
                if strand1 == strand:
                    if cluster & lncRNA:
                         print name,annote,'transcript'
                         continue
                     else:
                         continue
                 continue
        break
```

Comment: What is printed if you add `print line` after the `for line in f1`?

Answer (score 3):

After the first line in `f1` you've already read all lines from `f2` file therefore `for line2 in f2` has zero iteration for the second and following lines in `f1` file unless `f2` file grows on disk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def intersect(r1, r2):
    return r2[0] < (r1[-1]+1) and r1[0] < (r2[-1]+1)

with open(sys.argv[2]) as f2:
     chrC_set, strand_set, clusters = set(), set(), []
     for i, line in enumerate(f2):
         parts = line.split()
         if len(parts) != 6:
            print >>sys.stderr, "%d line has %d parts: %s" % (i, len(parts), line),
            continue
         chrC, clustStart, clustEnd, annote, _, strand = parts
         chrC_set.add(chrC)
         strand_set.add(strand)
         clusters.append((xrange(int(clustStart), int(clustEnd)), annote))

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1:
     for i, line in enumerate(f1):
         parts = line.split()
         if len(parts) < 6:
            print >>sys.stderr, "%d line has %d parts: %s" % (i, len(parts), line),
            continue
         chrR, chrStart, chrEnd, name, _, strand1 = parts[:6]
         if strand1 == '-' and chrR in chrC_set and strand1 in strand_set:
            lncRNA = xrange(int(chrStart), int(chrEnd))
            for cluster, annote in clusters:
                if intersect(cluster, lncRNA):
                   print name, annote, 'transcript'
```

Comment: With your definition of **intersect()**, the result of ``intersect(xrange(10,21),xrange(20,31))`` is **False** . I don't think it's what you wanted. - Please, see my answer and give me your opinion.

Comment: @eyquem: well spotted. I've updated the answer. The formula works for [start, end) where `end` must not be in the range (past the last element in the range).

Answer (score 1):

The test `if strand1 == '-'` doesn't depend from the contents of **f2**. Hence you can put it before looping in **f2** and launch the exam of all the content of **f2** only if the current line of **f1** is containing a **strand1** with value '-'

Given also the fact that there is first `if strand1 == '-'` and then `if strand1 == strand`, it means that you are also interested only by lines in **f2** in which the **strand** has a value '-'.

Moreover, I took the idea of J.F.Sebastian to test the intersection of two ranges without help of sets, but only testing the bounds of the ranges. However, it isn't necessary to use a **range** nor an **xrange**, testing the bounds is enough.

So, I propose the following code, as a simple improvement of your algorithm:

```
for line in f1:
    (chrR,chrStart,chrEnd,name,score,strand1,codingStart,codingEnd,
     itemRbg,blockCount,blockSize,BlockStart) = line.strip().split()
    if strand1 == '-':
        s,e = int(chrStart), int(chrEnd)
        for line in f2:
            chrC,clustStart,clustEnd,annote,score,strand = line.strip().split()
            if strand=='-' and chrR == chrC \
               and int(clustStart)<e and s<int(clustEnd):
                print name,annote,'transcript'
        f2.seek(0,0)
```

.

However, this algorithm (yours, corrected) is poor: there is a complete reading of the content of **f2** for each line of **f1** containing a **strand1** with value '-'.

The algorithm of J.F.Sebastian is far better.
I improved it just a little, with the ideas expressed above.

```
with open(sys.argv[2]) as f2:
    clusters = []
    for i, line in enumerate(f2):
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts) != 6:
            print >>sys.stderr, "%d line has %d parts: %s" % (i,len(parts),line),
            continue
        chrC, clustStart, clustEnd, annote, _, strand = parts
        if strand=='-':
            clusters.append((chrC, int(clustStart), int(clustEnd), annote))

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1:
    for i, line in enumerate(f1):
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts) < 6:
            print >>sys.stderr, "%d line has %d parts: %s" % (i,len(parts),line),
            continue
        chrR, chrStart, chrEnd, name, _, strand1 = parts[:6]
        if strand1 == '-':
            for chrC,iclustStart,iclustEnd,annote in clusters:
                if chrR == chrC \
                   and iclustStart<int(chrEnd) and int(chrStart)<iclustEnd:
                    print name, annote, 'transcript'
```

Comment: 1. `xrange()` is required to check that the boundaries are sane otherwise the formula for `intersect()` might fail silently. 2. There is no complete reading of `f2` for each line in `f1`; `f2` is completely exhausted after the first time it's been read. 3. You are missing `if strand == '-'` before `clusters.append` for `f2` file. 4. the condition for intersection should be: `iclustStart<int(chrEnd) and int(chrStart)<iclustEnd`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You're right for 3 and 4 and I corrected. - Concerning 1, I suppose that ``clustStart <= clustEnd`` and ``chrStart <= chrEnd`` are always True; is it what you call sane values for the ranges ? - Concerning the point 2, I think you allude to the improvement of Will's algorithm; I corrected. - BTW I upvote your answer.

Comment: 1. yes, if start < end 2. quote: *"However, your algorithm is poor: there is a complete reading of the content of f2 for each line of f1 containing a strand1 with value '-'."* -- it is not correct, after the first time `f2` is at eof so the loop breaks immediately i.e., there is no complete reading for each line.. 4. `range(start, end)` doesn't include `end` therefore the intersection condition should be `<`, not `<=`. In my formula `r[-1]+1 == end`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian 2. I should have written: Will, the principle of your algorithm is to make a complete reading of the second file for each line read in the first file, but for that you need to move the second file's pointer represented by **f2** back to the beginning of the file. However, this algorithm, after addition of ``f2.seek()``, and even after having put the instruction ``if strand1 == '-'`` before the loop ``for line in f2``and not inside it, is poor in its principle, apart the fact it is badly written, because there are many repetitions of the complete reading of the second file.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian 4. Yes, **range(start, end)** doesn't include **end**, but **xrange(start,end)[-1]** isn't **end**, it is naturally **end-1**. For example, **xrange(10,21)[-1]** is 20, not 21. So, when evaluating **intersect(xrange(10,21),xrange(20,31))** , there is the comparison ``20 as xrange(20,31)[0] < 20 as xrange(10,21)[-1]`` and that is **False** though 20 is in range(10,21) AND range(20,31)

Comment: your code is wrong if you'd like to find whether `range(iclustStart, iclustEnd)` and `range(int(chrStart), int(chrEnd))` intersect. See previous comment: `(r[-1] + 1) == end`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Oh, you are right, evidently: I must write conditions ``int(clustStart)<e and s<int(clustEnd)`` and ``iclustStart<int(chrEnd) and int(chrStart)<iclustEnd``. I don't understand why a) I wrote _"You're right for 3 and 4 and I corrected"_ and I didn't correct yet b) I explained in my previous comment the reason why your first **intersect()** wasn't correct while you were speaking of MY code. This time, I effectively correct MY code.

Answer (score 0):

You are purposely doing a "continue" after finding the first hit. and then also doing a "break" after the first line.

You don't need to do that. The second loop will continue onto the next line in f2 just fine.
Then, when it gets to the end of f2 - it'll go onto the next line in f1. 
If you relaly want to check every line in f1 against every line in f2 then all those continues (and the break) are superfluous.

Try:

```
for line in f1:
     chrR,chrStart,chrEnd,name,score,strand1,codingStart,codingEnd,itemRbg,blockCount,blockSize,BlockStart = line.strip().split()
    chr = range(int(chrStart), int(chrEnd))
    lncRNA = set(chr)
    for line2 in f2:
            chrC,clustStart,clustEnd,annote,score,strand = line2.strip().split()
            clust = range(int(clustStart), int(clustEnd))
            cluster = set(clust)
            if strand1 == '-':
                    if chrR == chrC:
                            if strand1 == strand:
                                    if cluster & lncRNA:
                                            print name,annote,'transcript'
```

Comment: `f2` has been read to the end after the first line in `f1`, so without calling `f2.seek` (or `f2` file growing on disk) `for line2 in f2` won't return any lines.

Comment: ok, I'm confused - how does reading hte first line out of f1 also update f2's seek index?

Comment: When you are on the 2nd line in the `f1` file (i.e. after the 1st line) the `for line2 in f2` loop already iterated over all lines in `f2` file.

Comment: Ah I see. Good point. So yes I agree - need a seek to beginning before the "for line2".